# How do I use a DB procedure from the django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

For example, in MySQL, I would write:

```
SELECT id, my_calc(id, '2022-09-26') as calculated
FROM items;
```

How do I tell the ORM to use this DB procedure and pass the parameters?
Would I have to define a `Func`?

```
Items.objects.annotate(calculated=...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the new  function:

```py
from django.db.models import Func

class MyCalc(Func):
    function = 'my_calc'
    arity = 2 # requires 2 arguments
```

Use it:

```py
from django.db.models import Value

Items.objects.annotate(calculated=MyCalc(F('id'), Value('2022-09-26'))
```

Comment: Too much code for one function

Comment: Not sure to follow. 2 lines to define the `MyCalc` `Func` is too much code?

Answer (score 1):

obviously through Func expression.
More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

in your case (postgres):

```
self.annotate(calculated=Func(F('id'), Value('2022-09-26), function='public.MY_CALC', output_field=CharField()))
```